# Javascript variable equals another variable below doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, variables, countdown

So I have this countdown code:

```
countdowntime = '3'


var time_left = countdowntime;
var cinterval;

function time_dec(){
  time_left--;
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = time_left;
  if(time_left == 0){
    clearInterval(cinterval);alert('yes!');
  }
}
cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);

document.write('Time: <span id="countdown">', countdowntime ,'</span>');
```

I want to use `countdowntime='3'` **bellow** the code:

```
var time_left = countdowntime;
var cinterval;

function time_dec(){
  time_left--;
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = time_left;
  if(time_left == 0){
    clearInterval(cinterval);alert('yes!');
  }
}
cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);

document.write('Time: <span id="countdown">', countdowntime ,'</span>');


countdowntime = '3'
```

But then it stops working! 
I've tried to fix it by using functions and other ways with variables but it didn't came up working.. Please help me to resolve it..

Comment: I've got it working without another variable. One thing `time_left = 3` can't be used below document.write, but it's easy to bypass it.. Here's the working code:

    `var time_left;
    var cinterval;
    
    function time_dec(){
      time_left--;
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = time_left;
      if(time_left == 0){
        clearInterval(cinterval);alert('yes!');
      }
    }
    cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);
    
    
    
    time_left = 3
    
    
    
    document.write('Time: <span id="countdown">', time_left ,'</span>');`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your samples, the first one here appears to be initializing it correctly.

```
countdowntime = '3'


var time_left = countdowntime;
```

Based on the snippet you've shown, it's probably not working because you're not initializing it in the second sample until it gets to the bottom.

In fact, this is most likely where it's failing in the second:

```
time_left--;
```

`time_left` is probably not initialized. Check it in Firebug or the Chrome dev tools.

Comment: The code doesn't work without `time_left--;`, but anyway thanks for your answer!